# Email to new top level domain not working properly in iOS

Tags: ios

We have published an iPad app which uses the built-in email composer (MFMailComposeViewController) and we received the feedback from our user:

> Just a note, it does not seem to email out to the new top level
>   domains i.e. Someone@adomain.house the new domains which end in all
>   sorts of things like .menu .builders etc... I think it is an issue
>   with the app as I can send to those domains via the normal mail app on
>   the ipad.

Any idea what cause the problem occurred when I call to the built-in email composer?

Comment: Not enough information. How do you deliver the messages? Any logging from mail servers? Any logging at all?

Comment: You are unable to control the send process from `MFMailComposeViewController`, so you can't affect deliverability. It's *possible* there's a bug in iOS that affects the compose controller but not the Mail app. Have you attempted doing this yourself?

Comment: Any warnings or error messages in the console? What exactly happens?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior about greetings in questions.

Comment: Did you figure this out? If so, please accept my answer below and close this question as resolved.

Answer (score 2):

I've just tested (iOS 7) sending an email using built-in `MFMailComposeViewController` to `.technology` domain — it worked as expected and the message was delivered. No warnings or error messages, nothing. I believe it should work for other new TLDs like `.house`.

Just in case, here's the code how you should create and present `MFMailComposeViewController`:

```
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
    MFMailComposeViewController *composeViewController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    composeViewController.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [composeViewController setSubject:@"Subject"];
    [composeViewController setToRecipients:@[@"someone@adomain.house"]];

    [self presentViewController:composeViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

} else {
    // show alert to the user that the device is not configured for email
}`
```